# how to convert hex string values to byte[] in c#

Tags: c#, string, byte

I have got a string for instance:

```
"FF AA 1A 23 DF"
```

The only thing I want to get is a *byte array* that contains the following bytes:

```
[FF, AA, 1A, 23, DF..]
```

Somehow can I do a conversion like this?

Comment: What have you tried so far that hasn't worked? What google/stackoverflow searches have you tried?

Comment: Just paste your entire title into google and you will find hunders of answers (on this site too).

Comment: Please read [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is [old](https://stackoverflow.com/q/311165/1997232) indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try *Linq*: `Split` and `Convert`

```
 string source = "FF AA 1A 23 DF";

 byte[] result = source
   .Split(' ')                               // Split into items 
   .Select(item => Convert.ToByte(item, 16)) // Convert each item into byte
   .ToArray();                               // Materialize as array
```